# Configure Xorg to use integrated Intel, not Nvidia

Tags: display, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

I know I should change the configuration in something like a `20-intel.conf` file that should be somewhere, but I could not find it and I suspect that might highlight deeper problems, it is not in `/use/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` does not exist.

With `lspci -k` I can see the display controller, kernel driver in use and kernel modules are `i915`.

System is Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I have found much information on the internet, but most seems outdated, increasing confusion. Please help me to improve this question.

Comment: Intel is missing apparently because I have a `i7-9700K` and in `18.04` I only have version `2.1.0` of `i915-va-driver` when I would need version `2.3.0`, I might upgrade to `19.04` for it. `lspci -k` was not showing the version number.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a `20-intel.conf` file. You can do so by running this command:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Add the following information in the file:

```
Section “Device”
      Identifier “Intel Graphics”
      Driver “Intel”
      Option “DRI” “3”
EndSection
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

Comment: I think you mean `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`. Files under `/usr/share` are supposed to be managed by apt.